# Cant get Stored Procedure to run in parallel to logging task in C# Winform

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, async-await

I am a newbie with C#. I am trying to get a task to run in parallel to a stored procedure execution. So for example - I have a stored procedure which in this instance will just be running WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'. During that ten seconds a label will be populated with text which will have full stops added and then remove as you would see in a loading screen.

Disabling Replication.
Disabling Replication..
Disabling Replication...

Once the proc is completed it will break out of the while loop. This is being handled by a boolean value. So _IsRunning = false, run stored procedure then set IsRunning = true. The code works exactly as I would want it to if I just use Thread.Sleep(1000), which I used for test purposes, instead of a stored procedure.

Can someone tell me why this will not work when using the stored procedure? It just gets stuck on the while loop and constantly says Disabling Replication with the loading full stops.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsynchronousCoding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataAccess _access = new DataAccess();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        


        private async Task LoadRapport()
        {

            await DisableReplication();


        }


        private async Task DisableReplication()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(TestMethod);
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ShowProgressText("Disabling Replication"));
        }

        private bool _IsRunning;

        private void TestMethod()
        {
            _isRunning= false;
            //Thread.Sleep(10000);
            _access.Rapport_ReplicationSetting();
            _isRunning= true;
        }


        private void ShowProgressText(string txt)
        {
            var count = 0;
            var logText = new StringBuilder();

            logText.Append(txt);
            var baseLen = logText.Length;

            while (!_isRunning)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                if (count >= 3)
                {
                    logText.Remove(baseLen, count);
                    count = 0;
                }

                logText.Append(".");
                count++;

                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { UpdateProgressText(logText.ToString()); }));

            }

            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { UpdateProgressText(txt + " - Complete"); }));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        private void UpdateProgressText(string txt)
        {
            lblProgress.Text = txt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadRapport();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are [mixing non-blocking with blocking code](https://medium.com/@DomBurf/blocking-asynchronous-code-89d6ff5bbe22). This is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Additionally, I can't find the definition of `FakeSearch` in your code.

Comment: Apologies. I have amended that. It should be TestMethod().

Comment: I guess executing your stored procedure crashes without you noticing as you start it on an unwatched background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simple example with `CancellationToken` usage. I don't suggest `bool`, it's not Thread-safe.

```csharp
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => lblProgress.Text = s);
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource());
    {
        Task animationTask = ProgressAnimationAsync(progress, cts.Token);
        await DoSomeJobAsync();
        // await Task.Run(() => DoSomeHeavyJob()); // uncomment for test
        cts.Cancel();
        await animationTask;
    }
}

private async Task ProgressAnimationAsync(IProgress progress, CancellationToken token)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        progress.Report("Loading" + new string("." , i));
        i = i == 3 ? 1 : i + 1;
        await Task.Delay(250);
    }
}

// as I/O-bound operation
private async Task DoSomeJobAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}

// as CPU-bound operation
private void DoSomeHeavyJob()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

There's two different methods, you can test both.

Note: it's safe to use `lblProgress.Text` directly here, without `IProgress` synchronized callback. It's given here just for example. Create `new Progress` in UI Thread and you may call `.Report()` from any other Thread safely without `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

You can learn more about X-bound operations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: I am trying to understand exactly what your code suggestion is doing line by line but it is confusing me. It works great but I would like to understand what it is doing. I think it is just above my knowledge level. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlfieHillier read the article by the link at the end of the answer first. :) You're welcome.